# Vuejs - Event delegation and v-for context reference

Tags: vuejs2, v-for

I'm using the following snippet to render a list:

```html
<div @click.prevent="myhandler($event)"><!-- Delegated event handler-->
    <div class="tasks" v-for="(task, subName) in step.tasks">
        <button type="button">
            {{ task.caption }}
        </button>
        <span> {{ task.callableName }} </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
methods: {
    myhandler(e){
        // Event target may be a button element.
        let target = e.target;
        // …
        // Let's assume we know 'target' is a button element instance.
        // I wish I could have access to the v-for item ("task") which is associated in some ways to the button that was clicked.
        // let the_task_reference = ?;
    }…
```

Is there a clean way so that I could reach the `v-for` scope specific task related to that button?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to store the index of the task on the button.

```
<div class="tasks" v-for="(task, index) in step.tasks">
    <button type="button" :data-index="index">
        {{ task.caption }}
    </button>
    <span> {{ task.callableName }} </span>
</div>
```

And in your handler get the task using the index.

```
myhandler(evt){
  const task = this.step.tasks[evt.target.dataset.index]
  ...
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/QvmmZV?editors=1010).

If you had something stronger like an `id`, that would be even better.

**Not Recommended**

There is a hidden property, `__vue__` that is added to Vue and Component root elements. Were you to iterate over a component, you would be able to do something [like in this example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/YVavXR?editors=1010).

I wouldn't recommend that approach because it relies heavily on Vue internals that could change from version to version, but it's there today.

Comment: That's what I thought about. I will probably go for it since there seems to be no other neat alternative. I'll let the question live for maybe one more day and consider your answer as the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward solution would be to put the event handler on the same `div` as the `v-for` directive and just pass in the `task` variable:

```
<div 
  class="tasks" 
  v-for="(task, subName) in step.tasks"
  @click.prevent="myhandler(task, $event)"
>
  <button type="button">{{ task.caption }}</button>
  <span>{{ task.callableName }}</span>
</div>
```

---

If you really need to use an event handler on a parent element, you could keep track of the clicked task via a component property and add an extra click handler to the div with the `v-for` directive:

```
<div @click.prevent="myhandler($event)"
  <div 
    class="tasks" 
    v-for="(task, subName) in step.tasks" 
    @click="clickedTask = task"
  >
    <button type="button">{{ task.caption }}</button>
    <span>{{ task.callableName }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You would need to add a `clickedTask` property:

```
data() {
  return {
    clickedTask: null,
  }
}
```

And then in the handler you could refer to the task via `this.clickedTask`.

Comment: Thank you, but I know that. As I mentioned, I need to use event delegation here. In other words, I want the first common ancestor to handle the event and that means that I need a way to reference the task object when I only have access to the button element being the event target.

Comment: @Stphane there's no way to directly access the `task` variable from an event outside of its scope. You'll need to set an additional reference. See my update

Comment: I thought some hidden property on the vue instance would help but it appears that such thing does not exist. I fear your final solution leads to too much overhead. First because a click handler would still be registered on each v-for div element (which I wanted to avoid in the first place), secondly a new proxied data would be required. I will dig in, and let you know what I ended up with. Again, thank you.